# Can't figure out how to add favorites in list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and I am using [swipe list view](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) library to add swipe functionality to list view. Initially if I long click on the list item that list item would be added to my favorites. Instead of long click I want to implement the process of adding to favorites by swipe menu item click. But I am not sure of how to implement it

**my code for onitemlongclick**

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3)
{
    ImageView fvrtebutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);


    String tag = fvrtebutton.getTag().toString();
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        shrdPreference.addFavorite(InterActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
        Toast.makeText(InterActivity.this, getString(R.string.fav_added),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        fvrtebutton.setTag("yes");
        fvrtebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
    } else {
        shrdPreference.removeFavorite(InterActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
        fvrtebutton.setTag("no");
        fvrtebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        Toast.makeText(InterActivity.this,
                       getString(R.string.fav_removed),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + position);


    return false;
}
```

**my swipe menu item and its onclick**

```
SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // create "open" item
                SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(InterActivity.this);
                // set item background
                openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9,
                                                                   0xCE)));
                // set item width
                openItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                // set item title
                openItem.setTitle("Open");
                // set item title fontsize
                openItem.setTitleSize(18);
                // set item title font color
                openItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

                // create "delete" item
                SwipeMenuItem favoriteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(InterActivity.this);
                // set item background
                favoriteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                                                                     0x3F, 0x25)));
                // set item width
                favoriteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                // set a icon
                favoriteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.unfavorite);

                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(favoriteItem);


            }
        };
        // set creator
        listview.setMenuCreator(creator);

        listview.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                    //ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            // open
                            //open(item);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // favorite

                if(favoriteItem.getIcon().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unfavorite))){
                    Toast.makeText(InterActivity.this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Can't apply getTag() to swipe menu item
Even tried comparing drawable using equals() but getting a nullpointerexception

**getview () of my adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beg_list_item,null);
        holder.listHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemTextView);

        holder.listHash = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_hashtags);
        holder.alphabetList = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemImageView);

        holder.favariteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

        view.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) getItem(position);
    holder.listHeading.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHeading());
    holder.listHash.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHashText());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(codeList.get(position).getAlphabetimg(),
                             holder.alphabetList);


    if (checkFavoriteItem(codes)) {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("yes");
    } else {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("no");
    }                    





    return view;
}

public boolean checkFavoriteItem(CodeList checkCodes) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<CodeList> favorites = shrdprfrnce.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (CodeList codes : favorites) {
            if (codes.equals(checkCodes)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

**This is the method I tried**

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                    //ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            // open
                            //open(item);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // favorite

                CodeList codes = (CodeList) getItem(position);
                ImageView fvrtebutton= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

                            if (checkFavoriteItem(codes)){
                                shrdPreference.removeFavorite(InterActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
        fvrtebutton.setTag("no");
        favoriteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        fvrtebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        Toast.makeText(InterActivity.this,
                       getString(R.string.fav_removed),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else{

                                shrdPreference.addFavorite(InterActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
        Toast.makeText(InterActivity.this, getString(R.string.fav_added),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        fvrtebutton.setTag("yes");
        fvrtebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
        favoriteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite);
                                }


                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                private boolean checkFavoriteItem(CodeList checkCodes) {
                    boolean check = false;
                    List<CodeList> favorites = shrdPreference.getFavorites(InterActivity.this);
                    if (favorites != null) {
                        for (CodeList codes : favorites) {
                            if (codes.equals(checkCodes)) {
                                check = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return check;
                }



                private Object getItem(int position)
                {
                    return codelist.get(position);
                }
            });
```

**my line 230 is**

```
favoriteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite)
```

**my logcat**

> 13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime Process:
>   com.enlightenme.pac, PID: 4689 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E
>       AndroidRuntime java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuItem.setIcon(int)' on a null
>   object reference 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime  at
>   com.enlightenme.pac.InterActivity$RemoteDataTask$100000001.onMenuItemClick(InterActivity.java:230)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView$100000000.onItemClick(SwipeMenuListView.java:78)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuView.onClick(SwipeMenuView.java:85)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689
>   4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E
>       AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 01-13
>   15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689
>   4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 01-13
>   15:46:21.796 4689 4689 D     AndroidRuntime
>                                 Shutting down VM 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRunti13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.enlightenme.pac, PID: 4689 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E
>       AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuItem.setIcon(int)' on a null
>   object reference 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.enlightenme.pac.InterActivity$RemoteDataTask$100000001.onMenuItemClick(InterActivity.java:230)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView$100000000.onItemClick(SwipeMenuListView.java:78)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuView.onClick(SwipeMenuView.java:85)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689
>   4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E
>       AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 01-13
>   15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689
>   4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 01-13 15:46:21.801
>   4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRuntime
>                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 01-13
>   15:46:21.796 4689 4689 D     AndroidRuntime
>                                 Shutting down VM 01-13 15:46:21.801 4689 4689 E     AndroidRunti

Comment: what are you storing in `tag`? i mean what value you are storing when using `setTag()`?

Comment: @RRR SetTag to swipe menu item or fvrtbtn?. Didn't understand your question

Comment: setTag to fvrtebutton

Comment: @RRR If it is in favorites then yes, if not no

Comment: from where you are getting whether is favorite or not?

Comment: @RRR That is why I am using equalsignorecase() and it is not preset

Comment: post your adapter's `getView()` code

Comment: @RRR Ya will do it right now

Comment: @RRR Bro posted it have a look

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `checkFavoriteItem()` in your `getView` to check whether it's in favorite list or not, you can use same method in your `onMenuItemClick`.

You will get position of clicked item so,

```
 case 1:
     //favorite
      CodeList codes = (CodeList) getItem(position);
      if (checkFavoriteItem(codes))
         //its in favorite list, do coding for remove from favorite
      else
         //its not in favorite list, do coding to add it in favorite
```

Comment: I'll try it now and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Tried it but when I click, the app crashes but when I reopen the activity the clicked items are added to favorites. Posted the method I tried and the logcat